# How to share Background SpriteNode among Multiple Scenes?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Well, the title says it all. If I am currently in a presented Scene of which I have initialized a Background SpriteNode to be a class constant, then how do I use the same Background SpriteNode in my next presented scene without having to create another SpriteNode that behaves and looks exactly the same as in the previous scene.

Will creating another SpriteNode be costly, assuming the background object loads its texture from a texture atlas?

And, I am using Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
backgroundSprite.removeFromParent()
nextScene.addChild(backgroundSprite)
```

Comment: Would this be used in methods that handle touch events? If I'm in scene A, its onTouch methods would have the above code along with transitioning to the next scene. Ok thanks, I think I got it